# How can I convert XML to an associative array and control what attributes to use as the name value pairs?

Tags: php, xml, associative-array

I am setting up an automated program that pulls client information out of a CRM using a CURL request on their API. The information i get back needs to be converted to an array and sent over to our email platform.

When I make the initial CURL request the XML returned is along the lines of:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Leads>
 <Lead Id="1089686" LeadTitle="Student interested in Program" CreateDate="09/14/2018 19:52:28" ModifyDate="01/18/2019 08:37:07" ActionCount="7" LogCount="158" ReminderCount="0" ReadOnly="false" Flagged="false" LastDistributionDate="01/18/2019 08:37:07" LeadFormType="">
  <Campaign CampaignId="1253" CampaignTitle="Web Lead" />
  <Status StatusId="17" StatusTitle="Not Interested" />
  <Agent AgentId="11416" AgentName="user agent" AgentEmail="emails@email.com" GroupId="21" GroupName="group name">
   <AgentCustomFields custom1="" custom2="" custom3="" custom4="" />
  </Agent>
  <Fields>
   <Field FieldId="3" Value="email@email.com" FieldTitle="Email" FieldType="Email" />
   <Field FieldId="4" Value="Jon" FieldTitle="First Name" FieldType="Text" />
   <Field FieldId="5" Value="Doe" FieldTitle="Last Name" FieldType="Text" />
   <Field FieldId="11" Value="5554122222" FieldTitle="Mobile" FieldType="Phone" />
   <Field FieldId="105" Value="SensitiveURL.com" FieldTitle="Comments (Main)" FieldType="LongText" />
   <Field FieldId="117" Value="2002" FieldTitle="HS Grad Year" FieldType="Dropdown" />
   <Field FieldId="182" Value="Lack of Commitment" FieldTitle="Not Interested Reason" FieldType="ConditionalDropdown" />
   <Field FieldId="213" Value="Program" FieldTitle="Program of Interest" FieldType="ConditionalDropdown" />
   <Field FieldId="215" Value="text back - no not interested" FieldTitle="Comments (Nurture)" FieldType="LongText" />
   <Field FieldId="230" Value="Fort Myers" FieldTitle="Campus" FieldType="ConditionalDropdown" />
   <Field FieldId="276" Value="5554122222" FieldTitle="SMS Phone" FieldType="Phone" />
   <Field FieldId="291" Value="9/15/2018 10:09:12" FieldTitle="SMS Date Last Interacted" FieldType="DateTime" />
   <Field FieldId="292" Value="9/15/2018 10:09:12" FieldTitle="SMS Date Last Delivered" FieldType="DateTime" />
   <Field FieldId="295" Value="1" FieldTitle="SMS Delivered Count" FieldType="Number" />
   <Field FieldId="296" Value="False" FieldTitle="SMS Last Delivery Failed" FieldType="Checkbox" />
   <Field FieldId="297" Value="Long String" FieldTitle="SMS Last Delivered" FieldType="LongText" />
   <Field FieldId="299" Value="5554122222" FieldTitle="SMS Last Phone Delivered To" FieldType="Phone" />
  </Fields>
  <logs>
   <!-- a lot of superfluous information -->
  </logs>
 </Lead>
</Leads>
```

Then I use this bit of PHP to get it into an associative array where $data[0] is what's returned from the curl request minus the headers:

```
$data   = simplexml_load_string( $data[0], 'SimpleXMLElement', LIBXML_COMPACT | LIBXML_PARSEHUGE );
```

What I would like the array to look like is:

```
array = (
     'First Name' => 'Jon',
     'Last Name' => 'Doe',
)
```

But what i get is:

```
array = (
     '4' => 'Jon',
     '5' => 'Doe'
)
```

So what I am wondering is how can I control what the name value pairs are going to be? That way instead of it setting up an array where it grabs the first attribute in the XML and assigns it as the name, it will look for my chosen attributes to create the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure how you obtain the current output you have, but to extract the data and index by the `FieldTitle` attribute is something like...

```
$output = [];
foreach ( $data->Lead->Fields->Field as $field )  {
    $output[(string)$field['FieldTitle']] = (string)$field['Value'];
}

print_r($output);
```

Make sure that you cast the attributes as strings (using `(string)`) otherwise they are SimpleXMLElements.

For your sample data this gives..

```
Array
(
    [Email] => test@icloud.com
    [First Name] => Jon
    [Last Name] => Doe
    [Mobile] => 5554132121
)
```

If there are multiple leads then you may have to alter the loop...

```
foreach ( $data->Lead as $lead )  {
    $output = [];
    foreach ( $lead->Fields->Field  as $field ) {
        $output[(string)$field['FieldTitle']] = (string)$field['Value'];
    }
    print_r($output);
}
```

Comment: Where would i put that? After I obtain the XML from the CURL request? Or after I I use the simplexml_load_string function? Yes they are all currently SimpleXMLElements, how would I convert them to string?

Comment: Put it after the `simplexml_load_string()`, `$data` is the loaded XML and the loop uses it as input.

Comment: Sorry, company pulled me into a meeting. I gave it a go and var_dumped/print_r/echo'd the result. The best I could get it to say was from the var_dump and it prints 'Null'.

Comment: Can you be more exact with the XML input as this will make the extract need updating.

Comment: As in the full XML document that is being returned to me? If that's what you want I can pull one a remove all sensitive information.

Comment: I just need enough to be able to test this - so you can cut out as much as needed.

Comment: Okay, I made an edit and provided more of the XML being returned.

Comment: I've updated the answer - just the line `foreach ( $data->Lead->Fields->Field as $field )  {`

Comment: Ah this was perfect thank you so much!! I don't have a lot of experience with XML and even less so handling it with PHP so thank you.

Comment: With SimpleXML, just consider it as an object hierarchy, as you can see the levels of object references directly relate to the XML structure.  Using array style access is for attributes.  Gets easier after a few times.